# Problem with Rigid body and Child Of constraint

Tags: armature, bones, constraints, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

thank you for your time, I've been following this tutorial: [How To Make Any Rig Into a Rag Doll in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUmIKWVrHZU), but I have a problem, I'm using the Child of constraint on my bones to parent them to the rigid body that will create the rag doll, but for some reason, when I start the simulation, some of my bones twist, the head of the bone is where the tail is supposed to be, as a result my mesh is flipped upside down.

I've tried using the copy location and copy rotation constraints, but the result is that the bones take up odd positions instead of staying in place even if i moved the origin of the rigid bodys.

I need help, this tutorial was supposed to take 3 minutes, I've been on it for 7 days because I keep getting stuck, I've solved all the other problems I faced with some research but I can't find anything on this one.

[image: Ragdoll Off with Mesh]
Ragdoll Off with Mesh
[image: Ragdoll ON with Mesh]
Ragdoll ON with Mesh
[image: Ragdoll Off]
Ragdoll Off
[image: Ragdoll ON]
Ragdoll ON
[How To Make Any Rig Into a Rag Doll in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUmIKWVrHZU)

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: here you go, thank you in advance[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=GPR10ln4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/GPR10ln4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cubes have negative scales, select them, apply their scale, select the bones in *Pose* mode, click on the *Set Inverse* button of each *Child Of* constraint.

Comment: Thank you so much, I probably would never have guessed that on my own, but it makes perfect sense now.